# show last number in x-axis data on pgfplot

Tags: pgfplots

How can I get the last number on the x-axis (in this case 40^7) to show up on the plot also?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable, booktabs}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{filecontents*}{nano.csv}
100 -79.374
101.801 -79.858
103.634 -78.587
105.501 -79.077
107.401 -78.735
109.335 -81.799
111.304 -82.298
34884753.53 -150.333
38828202.58 -152.993
39527488.85 -154.021
40000000    -153.788
\end{filecontents*}

\pgfplotsset{minor grid style={dashed,red}}
\pgfplotsset{major grid style={dotted,green!50!black}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogxaxis}[xmin = 100, xmax = 40e6, scale = .75, width=20cm,height=10cm, title = {\emph{(a) $P_{T}$ over different samples}},
x tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/fixed,
        /tikz/.cd
    }, xlabel={\emph{Offset Frequency (Hz)}},ylabel={\emph{Phase Noise (dBc/Hz)}}]

\addplot [blue]table[x index=0,y index=1,col sep=space] {nano.csv};

\end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\caption[Plot showing (a) position ${\mathbf{P_{T}}}$.]{Plot showing position ${\mathbf{P_{T}}}$.}\label{noise}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this:

[image]

For this I ad into `axis` option `extra x ticks = {4e7}`.

**Addendum:** According to your comment: you need to enlarge `xmax` to `4'e7` or better to 5E7.

**Note:**  Maximal `x` value in your table is `40e6` or  `4e7`, so there is not sense to have `xmax` 10 times bigger (i.e.: `40e7`).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable, booktabs}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{filecontents*}{nano.csv}
100 -79.374
101.801 -79.858
103.634 -78.587
105.501 -79.077
107.401 -78.735
109.335 -81.799
111.304 -82.298
34884753.53 -150.333
38828202.58 -152.993
39527488.85 -154.021
40000000    -153.788
\end{filecontents*}

\pgfplotsset{minor grid style={dashed,red}}
\pgfplotsset{major grid style={dotted,green!50!black}}

    \begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{semilogxaxis}[
            width = 15cm, height=7.5cm,
             xmin = 100, xmax = 50e6,
            title = {\emph{(a) $P_{T}$ over different samples}},
x tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed,
                    /tikz/.cd}, 
            xlabel={\emph{Offset Frequency (Hz)}},
            ylabel={\emph{Phase Noise (dBc/Hz)}},
    extra x ticks = {40e6}
                    ]
\addplot [blue]table[x index=0,y index=1,col sep=space] {nano.csv};
    \end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Plot showing position ${\mathbf{P_{T}}}$.}
\label{noise}
\end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, but how to modify the code so that it shows up as just "40^7" and not "4*10^7"?  That is, have the same format like the other numbers on the x-axis.  Thank you.

Comment: This should not be a problem ... see  addenda to my answer.